# extending methods with Protractor and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, protractor

I have `BasePage`and`HomePage`
How to extends BasePage?
I did something like this:

```
const HomePage = function () {
  HomePage.prototype = BasePage.prototype;
```

and I can't see methods from `BasePage` in `HomePage`
How to do with javascript? How to use BasePage methods globally? in all modules?

Comment: Recommend you to use ES6 which is the new JavaScript, with it you can simply to do as `class HomePage extend BasePage`

Comment: ok it good idea. but is it possible to get methods like I wrote above?

Answer (score 1):

```
// base.page.js

class BasePage {

   getTitle() {
      return browser.getTitle();
   }
}
module.exports = BasePage;
```

// home.page.js

```
const BasePage = require('./base.page');

class HomePage extends BasePage {
    logout() {
       ...
    }
}
module.exports = new HomePage();
```

// test.js

```
const homePage = require('./home.page');
expect(homePage.getTitle()).toEqual('xxx');
homePage.logout();
```